# Android Fullscreen Fragment Dialog Bug

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, nexus-4

I created a "fullscreen" DialogFragment, in which I added a tranparent-black background. The end result can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

Here's how I made it:

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // if >= LOLLIPOP, then I color the the statusbar
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            dialog.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(SOME_COLOR_HERE);
        }

    }

@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.DialogFullScreen);
    }
```

This is the theme I set on setStyle():

```
<style name="DialogFullScreen">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And this is the layout I inflate for the fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="br.com.emotiondigital.sempreeditora.Fragments.LockedContentFragment"
android:id="@+id/popup_parent_layout">


<LinearLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/popup_black_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#b9000000"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/popup_main_layout"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bg_popup"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bg_popup"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bg_popup"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bg_popup"
        android:background="@color/bg_grey"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/selectNewspaperText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/selecione_jornal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/topLine"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewJornais"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/bottomLine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancelar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/cancelar"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnOk"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/ok"/>

        </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Those screenshots were from a Xperia Z3 running Android 5.1
This is working fine on many devices, tested even on some low-end Samsung 4.2 devices. The problem is that it is not working on a Nexus 4, also with Android 5.1. On the Nexus 4, it seems the transparency is not working, and the view gets replicated many times on the background. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here's another comparison between the Xperia Z3 and the Nexus 4:

[image]

[image]

What's happening on the Nexus 4?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That is a strange graphical glitch, but why are you using a "full-screen" dialog in the first place? It seems like you are just replicating the default behavior of a dialog (dialogs dim the background by default).

Comment: @Bryan I like controlling all the aspects of my view. For example, this way I can control the background as a view and animate it's opacity in runtime.  I use this to create some interesting effects.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout for dialog then, use code below in onCreate or at the first of the dialog method.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Its work for me. I used a method to create dialog full screen.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me by using the following code in onCreate() `

```
 setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);`
```

use the following in onStart()

```
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```